# Redirect based on parameter

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a page based on the parameters passed.

I would like redirect

**rewrite ^/join_trial to /test? permanent;**

and

**rewrite ^/join_trial?discount=free(.*) /test2? permanent;**

The first one works, but the second one doesn't. It looks like nginx doesn't take (.*) regex.

For the first one, the following cases work.

**/join_trial?test=aaaaa**

**/join_trial?923849=aaa**

Basically, you can put anything after **/join_trial**.

I want to have a redirect when a user appends **?discount=free**(anything goes here).

Is this possible with nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match on a query string at all in a [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite). So you'll need to check the argument directly.

For instance:

```
if ($arg_discount ~ ^free) {
    rewrite ^/join_trial /test2? permanent;
}
rewrite ^/join_trial /test? permanent;
```

And I suspect you really **do not** want to be sending 301 redirects, as the user will then see `/test` or `/test2` right in their address bar. Perhaps you really mean to process these URLs internally only? In that case change `permanent` to `last`.